# multiple lines of annotation from CADD combined into one textstring

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, microstation

I am bringing a Microstation dgn file into ArcGIS using the conversion tool. The results include several lines of annotation for each property, each line of text is a separate record, i.e. line 1: owner name, line 2: parcel number, etc.

I was going to spatial join the text to the property polygons but I end up with text that creates multiple polygons.

Does anyone know how to group or combine these "blocks" of text so they are one record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Spatial Join, set Join Operation to JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE, right-click the Column you want the Annotation Values combined, set the Merge Rule to Join. In Properties, you can set the Delimiter to space,comma,etc. You may need to increase the Length of the Field to accommodate the concatenated values. Instead of using an existing field you can also add a new Field and manually set all the parameters in the Field Map dialog.

Comment: thank you. I will try that first thing Monday morning and will let you know how that works for me.

Comment: This would have worked if the annotation was cleaner. Thank you klewis, I marked it answered.